# Pinhole camera model definitions

Tags: matrix-equations, mathematical-modeling, computational-geometry, computer-vision

As I were implementing the pinhole camera model based on [Tsai](https://doi.org/10.1109/JRA.1987.1087109), I noticed that there were two conventions used. For opencv and others, the following is used:

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u_{c} \\\ v_{c} \\\ h_{c}
\end{pmatrix}
= R * P + T
$$

$$
\begin{matrix}
u_{n} = u_{c} / h_{c} &
v_{n} = v_{c} / h_{c}
\end{matrix}
$$

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u \\\ v \\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
= K * 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u_{n} \\\ v_{n} \\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, some researchers used the following definition:

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u_{c} \\\ v_{c} \\\ h_{c}
\end{pmatrix}
= R^{-1} * (P - T)
$$

$$
\begin{matrix}
u_{n} = u_{c} / h_{c} &
v_{n} = v_{c} / h_{c}
\end{matrix}
$$

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u \\\ v \\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
= K * 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u_{n} \\\ v_{n} \\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where

$$ 
P = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
X \\\ Y \\\ Z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ R = \begin{pmatrix}
r_1 & r_2 & r_3 \\
r_4 & r_5 & r_6 \\ 
r_7 & r_8 & r_9
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$
T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
t_{x} \\\ t_{y} \\\ t_{z}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
K = 
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{x} & 0 & c_{x} \\\ 0 & f_{y} & c_{y} & \\\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My problem is I do not know why the second definition is used. When using direct linear transform to estimate intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, the first definition is the only one I know that works. Furthermore, the first definition provides the correct $u$ and $v$ values for a given focal length, Euler angles, and translation vector. However, the second definition requires different values for the parameters and is harder to optimize through nonlinear minimization with error terms. The only reason why I can think of its use is the ease of which it is to back project points to a specified $Z$ plane. So, does anyone know why does this definition exists and can provide more information on its use?

P.S. Sorry for any ambiguity in my question as this is the first time using math.exchange and second time using forums for questioning at all. I searched for many definitions in the forums and other websites, but could not get any conclusive reasons why there are different definitions for perspective projection using the pinhole camera model.

Comment: Tsai published a paper in 1987 on camera calibration on consumer grade cameras. He proposed a two step camera model where the world coordinates are converted to camera coordinates (Wc = R * P + T, where Wc is a matrix containing uc, vc, and hc) and then scaled to pixel coordinates (p = K * Wn, where Wn are normalized camera coordinates). I think this is where a majority of camera models are based on. Anyhow, one can read more at https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1087109 if someone needs more information about the Tsai camera model.

Comment: Please include such information in the question itself

Comment: The second transformation is the inverse of the first (the $R$ transformation, not the $K$ rescaling). They are flipping the coordinate systems,

Comment: How would the coordinate system be flipped? When using world points (X, Y, Z), the inverse transformation seems to cause many problems when rescaling.  The reprojection errors of the OpenCV convention and the second definition (the inverse transformation) have vastly different values when performing nonlinear minimization. For the OpenCV convention, I got my camera down to ~0.5 pixel RMS (root mean square) error while the second definition hardly got below 60 pixels RMS error. Perhaps, the world coordinates have to be used differently?